# Will my car A/C cool better if my car's turbocharger is working (above 2500 rm)

Tags: ac, turbocharger

Title is self explanatory. I do not know how the car air conditioners or turbochargers really work and affect the power required to be produced by the engine. Can you all help me with it ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

Basically, no ... there's really no correlation between how the turbocharger works or makes power versus how well the A/C cools the vehicle. It does take power to run the A/C compressor. It takes power to run the alternator or water pump as well. So, when the A/C is doing its thing, there is less power available to propel the vehicle. A/C compressors really don't work better at higher RPMs, they can just do their job faster. Basically, the A/C compressor gets turned on when the pressures in the lines crop to a certain level, then kicks off when the pressures get correct. If the engine is spinning high enough, some compressors will kick off to ensure it isn't overspun, which might cause damage to it. Realistically, the turbo won't have much if any affect on the A/C and how it runs, other than it helps the engine produce more power, which the A/C can consume to compress the refrigerant.

Comment: I hope this answers your question, as the question was a bit vague. If it doesn't, post up here on comments what I might not have answered and I'll see what I can do to create a better answer for you.

Comment: Most car ac compressors are of the swash plate type so they control their delivery irrespective of rpm - even pumping zero at max rpm but that is how swash plates work...

Answer (score 0):

The turbocharger is designed to do one thing; force air into the engine intake air system to produce more power than the same engine without it. Turbochargers do nothing for the ac system. Vehicle ac systems draw power from the serpentine drive belt that distributes engine power to accessories; power steering, water pump, ac compressor, alternator, superchargers. Exhaust powers the turbocharger above idle rpm depending on manufacturing configurations. In general, turbochargers boost engine power when using anywhere from half to wide open throttle.